# Mapstruct to update values without overwriting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

Is there a way to instruct MapStruct to not overwrite values in the target?

For example:

```
public interface IMyMapper {
    IMyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(IMyMapper.class);
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "foo", source = "source.FOO"),
            @Mapping(target = "bar", source = "source.BAR2"),
    })
    void updateTargetEntity(@MappingTarget MyTarget target , MySource source);
}

class MyTarget {
 String a;
 String b;
 ...
}

class MySource {
 String a;
 String b;
 ...
}
```

Where for instance `target` will have `a = "asdf"`, and `source` will have `a = "zzz"`, I don't want `zzz` to overwrite `asdf`.

NOTE: I don't want to always ignore values, I just don't want to overwrite them if they exist.

I tried to look at the several mapping strategies here: http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/ but none of them seems to fit.

Comment: This is currently not supported within MapStruct. Usually when people are updating the objects they want to change the fields in the target instance. You are trying to do something else. Can you maybe provide some explanation of what exactly you are trying to do, maybe there is some other way to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently discussing this. There's a [PR](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1618) pending. Keep an eye out for that one. For BeanMappings, all the current strategies apply on the BeanMapping level, not on the property level. So, the NullValueMappingStrategy tells you what happens when an input bean (or Map, or List in case of MapMapping, IterableMapping) is null. There was (up till soon) no such thing what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm one of the MapStruct authors.