# Is there a way to prevent MapStruct from overwriting values during the update of a record?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I have seen that there was a similar question in 2018:
[Mapstruct to update values without overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755301/mapstruct-to-update-values-without-overwriting) but there was no example of solving this issue.

Thus, I could not figure out how to solve it.

I am using `Lombok` and `MapStruct`

`UserEntity` represents the table in the Database

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3549451006888843499L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     // this specifies that the id will be auto-incremented by the database
    private Long id;
    
    @Column( nullable = false)
    private String userId;
    
    @Column( nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column( nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column( nullable = false, length = 120)
    private String email;
    
    @Column( nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;   // I am encrypting the password during first insertion of a new record

}// end of class
```

`UserDTO` is used as  an intermediate between the `UserEntity` and the `UserRequestModel` (I will mention it later).

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2583091281719120521L;
    
//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  Attributes
//  ------------------------------------------------------
    private Long id;            // actual id from the database table
    private String userId;      // public user id
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String encryptedPassword;       // in the database we store the encrypted password  

}// end of class
```

`UserRequestModel` is used when a request arrives in the UserController.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class UserRequestModel {
    
//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  Attributes
//  ------------------------------------------------------
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    
}// end of class
```

I created a `UserMapper` interface which is used by `MapStruct`.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "password", ignore = true)
    UserDTO mapEntityToDto(UserEntity userEntity);

    @Mapping(target = "encryptedPassword")
    UserEntity mapDtoToEntity(UserDTO userDto);
    
    UserResponseModel mapDtoToResponseModel(UserDTO userDto);
    
    @Mapping(target = "encryptedPassword", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "userId", ignore = true)
    UserDTO mapUserRequestModelToDto(UserRequestModel userRequestModel);
    
}// end of interface
```

Finally, I use `UserResponseModel` to return a record to the client application.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class UserResponseModel {
    
//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  Attributes
//  ------------------------------------------------------
    
    // This is NOT the actual usedId in the database!!!
    // We should not provide the actual value. For security reasons.
    // Think of it as a public user id.
    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

}// end of class
```

The object above are used for the mapping. Now, I am going to show you the code from the `UserController` and the `UserService`. This issue occurs inside the `UserService` class.

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
public UserResponseModel updateUser(@PathVariable("id") String id , @RequestBody UserRequestModel userRequestModel) {
        
    UserResponseModel returnValue = new UserResponseModel();
        
    UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.mapUserRequestModelToDto(userRequestModel);
        
    // call the method to update the user and return the updated object as a UserDTO
    UserDTO updatedUser = userService.updateUser(id, userDTO);
        
    returnValue = userMapper.mapDtoToResponseModel(updatedUser);
        
    return returnValue;
        
}// end of updateUser
```

`UserService` is used to implement the business logic of the application.

```
@Override
public UserDTO updateUser(String userId, UserDTO user) {
        
    UserDTO returnValue = new UserDTO();
        
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        
    if(userEntity == null) {
        throw new UserServiceException("No record found with the specific id!");        // our own exception
    }
        
    // get the changes from the DTO and map them to the Entity
    // this did not work. The values of the Entity were set to null if they were not assigned in the DTO
    userEntity = userMapper.mapDtoToEntity(user);
        
    // If I set the values of the Entity manually, then it works
//      userEntity.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
//      userEntity.setLastName(user.getLastName());
//      userEntity.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        
    // save the Entity
    userRepository.save(userEntity);
        
    returnValue = userMapper.mapEntityToDto(userEntity);
        
    return returnValue;
        
}// end of updateUser
```

If I try to run this code, I get the following error.

[image]

I used the debugger in order to understand the issue and I noticed that the `MapStruct` was overwriting all the attributes and not only those that had been send in the request.

The code that was automatically generated by `MapStruct` is the following:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-11-01T11:56:36+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 3.21.0.v20200304-1404, environment: Java 11.0.9 (Ubuntu)"
)
@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {

    @Override
    public UserDTO mapEntityToDto(UserEntity userEntity) {
        if ( userEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();

        userDTO.setEmail( userEntity.getEmail() );
        userDTO.setEncryptedPassword( userEntity.getEncryptedPassword() );
        userDTO.setFirstName( userEntity.getFirstName() );
        userDTO.setId( userEntity.getId() );
        userDTO.setLastName( userEntity.getLastName() );
        userDTO.setUserId( userEntity.getUserId() );

        return userDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity mapDtoToEntity(UserDTO userDto) {
        if ( userDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

        userEntity.setEncryptedPassword( userDto.getEncryptedPassword() );
        userEntity.setEmail( userDto.getEmail() );
        userEntity.setFirstName( userDto.getFirstName() );
        userEntity.setId( userDto.getId() );
        userEntity.setLastName( userDto.getLastName() );
        userEntity.setUserId( userDto.getUserId() );

        return userEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public UserResponseModel mapDtoToResponseModel(UserDTO userDto) {
        if ( userDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserResponseModel userResponseModel = new UserResponseModel();

        userResponseModel.setEmail( userDto.getEmail() );
        userResponseModel.setFirstName( userDto.getFirstName() );
        userResponseModel.setLastName( userDto.getLastName() );
        userResponseModel.setUserId( userDto.getUserId() );

        return userResponseModel;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDTO mapUserRequestModelToDto(UserRequestModel userRequestModel) {
        if ( userRequestModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();

        userDTO.setEmail( userRequestModel.getEmail() );
        userDTO.setFirstName( userRequestModel.getFirstName() );
        userDTO.setLastName( userRequestModel.getLastName() );
        userDTO.setPassword( userRequestModel.getPassword() );

        return userDTO;
    }
}
```

Most probably, I am not doing something correctly.

Do you think the issue occurs because I do not have constructors? Normally Java automatically creates the no-arguments constructor, if we do not implement it.

I am adding the following image, so that I can demonstrate what I want to do. Maybe this flow can help.

[image]

Most probably the method `mapDtoToEntity` **should accept 2 attributes** in order to map the `UserDTO` to `UserEntity`. For instance:

```
userMapper.mapDtoToEntity(userDto, userEntity);
```

```
public UserEntity mapDtoToEntity(UserDTO userDto, UserEntity userEntity) {
        
    if( userDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }
        
    // set ONLY the attributes of the UserEntity that were assigned 
    // to the UserDTO by the UserRequestModel. In the current case only 3 attributes
        
    
    // return the updated UserEntity
        
}
```

Thank you [**Sergio Lema**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2460460/sergio-lema)!!! I added your modification in my code and everything worked!

**UPDATED VERSION**

I had to add the following method to `UserMapper` class.

```
@Mapping(target = "firstName", source = "firstName")
@Mapping(target = "lastName", source = "lastName")
@Mapping(target = "email", source = "email")
void updateFields(@MappingTarget UserEntity entity, UserDTO dto);
```

Then, I had to modify the `updateUser` method inside the `UserService` class.

```
@Override
public UserDTO updateUser(String userId, UserDTO user) {
        
    UserDTO returnValue = new UserDTO();

    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);

    if (userEntity == null)
            throw new UserServiceException(ErrorMessages.NO_RECORD_FOUND.getErrorMessage());
        
    // update only specific fields of userEntity
    userMapper.updateFields( userEntity, user);

    userRepository.save(userEntity);
        
    // map again UserEntity to UserDTO in order to send it back
    returnValue = userMapper.mapEntityToDto(userEntity);

    return returnValue;
        
}// end of updateUser
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the meaning of the fields "userId" and "id" in your UserEntity. Does it reference to a foreign key? If that's the case, you may inject the parent (or child) object before persisting the entity.

Comment: Hello @Sergio, I am using the **id** in the **UserEntity** to represent the **primary key**  of the table. For security reasons, I **do not want to send** this **id** to the client application. Thus, I **created a userId** which I use as a **public key**.

Comment: Which database do you use? I'm not sure to understand the concept of *public key*. Does it reference to another table in the database? Because it seems, with the error message you show, that the link between two tables is not satisfied.

Comment: I have only one table called **UserEntity** which has an auto-incremented primary key called **id**. Because I **do not want to show** to the client application what is the **actual value of the primary key**, I use another attribute called **userId**. This is something I want to have for security reasons. The issue occurs because a **new UserEntity is created by MapStruct** and the value **encryptedPassword** inside the **UserEntity** is set to **NULL**. **encryptedPassword** cannot be null!

Comment: Maybe you didn't copied it, but I don't see where you goes from **password** to **encryptedPassword**, because it's not in the incoming **UserRequestModel** from the controller. Do you generate a random value for the encryptedPassword?

Comment: This value is generated **once during the Insertion**.  
  userEntity.setEncryptedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword())); // encrypt the password                                                                                 **During the update**, I want to change only the **firstname**, **lastName** and **email**. The other attributes of the **UserEntity** should not change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, you are creating a new instance of `UserEntity` each time a PUT is done. What should be done is an update of the desired fields. For that, you can use `@MappingTarget` as following:

```
@Mapping(target = "targetFieldName", source = "sourceFieldName")
void updateFields(@MappingTarget UserEntity entity, UserDTO dto);
```

This annotation ensures that no new object is created, it will maintain the original object, just updating the desired fields.

Comment: Thank you @Sergio! Everything works well after your modification!!!